# Functions with empty parameter list in C99 is not compatible with C++98?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, c99, c++98

This is code compiled with GCC(with -std=c99) and G++(with -std=c++98):

```
void fun()
{}
int main()
{
    fun(1,2,3);
    return 0;
}
```

GCC compiled the code successfully,but the G++ came up with this:
`error: too many arguments to function ‘int fun()’`
I am totally confused.
I knew that the C++ should be compatible with C by design,but this case shows me incompatibility.This case happens by design?

Comment: C++ is by design *not* completely compatible with C, it's a totally different language.

Comment: C and C++ are different languages, for any combinations of respective versions.

Comment: No, there is no full compatibility between C99 & C++98 or C++11. You found one of the incompatible points

Comment: Since I am new to StackOverflow , your speed of answering me shocked me.Thanks to creator of website my mother will no longer worry about my studying!

Comment: Note that even in C you should avoid writing such code, specifying the parameters in declarations is really much better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C an empty parameter list means that you don't specify how many arguments the function takes. To define a function with 0 parameters, you'd use `(void)` as the parameter list. In C++ an empty parameter list means the function takes 0 parameters, so yes, C and C++ are not compatible in this instance.

> I knew that the C++ should be compatible with C by design,but this case shows me incompatibility.This case happens by design?

While C++ is compatible to C in many instances, this is not the case all the time. Other examples are implicit casts from `void*` (allowed in C, but not in C++) and keywords (it's perfectly valid to use something like `class` as a variable name in C, but obviously not in C++ where it is a keyword). And yes, that's by design.

Comment: OK.I got the point that I can`t write cpp code in the way of C.Thanks for your explaining.

Answer (score 4):

In c++

```
void fun();
```

means a function taking no arguments. 
To communicate that to C write

```
void fun(void); // also works in c++ but it's frowned upon
```